# Raster to Vector GDAL raster conversion error QGIS 3.28

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, vector, raster-conversion, polygonize

I'm trying to convert a raster layer with values 1 to 0 in vector layer using GDAL raster conversion - Polygonize (Raster to Vector) in QGIS 3.28.
After processing i got an error at the Log window:

> GDAL command:
> gdal_polygonize.bat %3Fcrs%3DEPSG%3A4326%26extent%3D22.14523000000000152%2C38.27817999999999898%2C22.56270999999999916%2C39.11314000000000135%26width%3D1181%26height%3D2362%26formula%3D%2522222%402%2522%253C160%26222%3Auri%3DC%3A%255CUsers%255CUser%255CDesktop%255Cgeology%2520prova%255Craster%2520prova%255C222.jpeg%26222%3Aprovider%3Dgdal -b 1 -f "GPKG" C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_hQdayx/bf22508f974243a8bbbb8a9b2e6a4dc9/OUTPUT.gpkg OUTPUT DN
> GDAL command output:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.9\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py", line 175, in main
> self.doit(**kwargs)
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.9\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 314, in doit
> return gdal_polygonize(**kwargs)
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.9\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 75, in gdal_polygonize
> src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename)
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.9\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 5337, in Open
> return _gdal.Open(*args)
> RuntimeError: `%3Fcrs%3DEPSG%3A4326%26extent%3D22.14523000000000152%2C38.27817999999999898%2C22.56270999999999916%2C39.11314000000000135%26width%3D1181%26height%3D2362%26formula%3D%2522222%402%2522%253C160%26222%3Auri%3DC%3A%255CUsers%255CUser%255CDesktop%255Cgeology%2520prova%255Craster%2520prova%255C222.jpeg%26222%3Aprovider%3Dgdal' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
> Process returned error code 1
> Execution completed in 0.51 seconds
> Results:
> {'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_hQdayx/bf22508f974243a8bbbb8a9b2e6a4dc9/OUTPUT.gpkg'}

> Loading resulting layers
> The following layers were not correctly generated.
> • C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_hQdayx/bf22508f974243a8bbbb8a9b2e6a4dc9/OUTPUT.gpkg
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

[image]

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Is your input something that is created on-the-fly with raster calculator or some other tool? Have you tried to save it as a GeoTIFF first?

Comment: Yes, you were right the raster was created on-the-fly. I saved the raster and processed it again and its working perfectly. Thank you @user30184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the source dataset that was created on-the-fly with the raster calculator tool. The Raster to Vector tool that runs gdal_polygonize on the background could not access the temporary raster layer that was created by the formula. The solution was to "materialize" the raster layer by saving it into a file for further processing with Raster to Vector.